# Error 400: SRVE0295E not able to invoke method inside controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

When i click on save button, it should go to my controller method but instead of it is giving error.
Tried searching but not able to resolve the issue.

**Request Mapping**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/qualification", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveOrUpdate(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
        @ModelAttribute Qualification qualification, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("Save");
    System.out.println(qualification.getCompany());
    return model;
}
```

**qualification.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tg" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<jsp:useBean id="pagedListHolder" scope="request" class="org.springframework.beans.support.PagedListHolder" />

<!-- Main Body Section Start -->
<main class="container padContnr">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Qualification Rules</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="bg-ltgreen padding-10 margin-t-10" id="QualSerch">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="#">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Company <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="company">
                 <option selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option>Dell Inc.</option>
<option>Deutsche Bank AG Frankfurt</option>
<option>Disney Worldwide Services</option>
<option>Energy Future Holdings</option>
<option>HCL</option>
<option>Hewlett-Packard</option>
<option>Pepsico</option>
<option>Shire Pharmaceuticals Inc.</option>
<option>Skandia </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Class <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="class">
                            <option selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option>Operating System</option>
                <option>Computer System</option>
                <option>EUC</option>
                <option>Processor</option>
                <option>Network Port</option>
                <option>Disk Drive</option>
                <option>Database Instance </option>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Status <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <select class="form-control" name="company">
                <option selected="selected">Active</option>
                <option>Inactive</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Rule <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <input class="form-control" name="rule" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-c margin-t-10">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btnSubmit" id="QualRule" type="button">GO</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="QualRules" class="disNone">
    <div class="row margin-t-10">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="f-size-16 display-inline-block float-l margin-r-20"> Items
          <select class="small border-radius2 margin-l-10">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <ul class="pagination margin-0 f-size-16 float-l">
          <li class="page-item disabled"> <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous"> <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> </li>
          <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link" href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next"> <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 flt-r padding-t-10"> <a href="Javascript:;" id="QualAdd" class="sprite add"></a> <a href="Javascript:;" id="EditBtn" class="sprite edit"></a> <a href="Javascript:;" id="Searchd" class="sprite search"></a> <a href="Javascript:;" id="DelBtn" class="sprite delete"></a> </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Table Details -->
    <div class="table-responsive margin-t-10">
      <table width="100%" border="0" class="table table-striped five trClick">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Rule</th>
            <th>Last Modified On</th>
            <th>Last Modified By</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Dell Inc.</td>
            <td>Operating System</td>
            <td>PEP_NE:QUAL_CS</td>
            <td>5/6/2016 05:30:20</td>
            <td>admin</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Deutsche Bank AG Frankfurt</td>
            <td>Computer System</td>
            <td>PEP_NE:QUAL_NW</td>
            <td>10/16/2015 15:40:32</td>
            <td>admin</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Disney Worldwide Services</td>
            <td>EUC</td>
            <td>EFH_NE:QUAL_CS</td>
            <td>12/6/2015 12:23:41</td>
            <td>admin</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Energy Future Holdings</td>
            <td>Processor</td>
            <td>EFH_NE:QUAL_NW</td>
            <td>11/26/2015 13:34:22</td>
            <td>admin</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-c margin-t-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bg-ltgreen padding-10 margin-t-10 disNone" id="QualEdit">
    <form:form class="form-horizontal" action="qualification" modelAttribute="qualification" method="post" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Company <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
             <form:select id="company" class="form-control" path="company">
                <form:option value="Select" />
                <form:options items="${companyList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="dropdownValue"/>
            </form:select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Class <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
             <form:select id="companyClass" class="form-control" path="companyClass" onchange="switchOption();">
                <form:option value="Select" />
                <form:options items="${classList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="dropdownValue"/>
            </form:select>              
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Status <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <form:select path="status" class="form-control">
                <form:options items="${statusList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="dropdownValue" />
              </form:select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Rule <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <form:input path="rule" class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="QualAtt"class="row margin-t-10">
        <div id="QualAtt1" class="col-md-6">
         <!--  <table id="master_table" class="myAttr f-size-16">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Attribute</th>
                <th>Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>  
                <td><input class="checkBoxSize" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Name </td>
                <td><input name="System" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input class="checkBoxSize" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Serial Number</td>
                <td><input name="Instance" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input class="checkBoxSize" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>CPU Count</td>
                <td><input name="Mainframe" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
              </tr>
                         <tr>
                <td><input class="checkBoxSize" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>RAM (MB)</td>
                <td><input name="Mainframe" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
              </tr>
                         <tr>
                <td><input class="checkBoxSize" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Operating System</td>
                <td><input name="Mainframe" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
              </tr>
                         <tr>
                <td><input class="checkBoxSize" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Is Virtual</td>
                <td><input name="Mainframe" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 margin-t-10">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btnSubmit" type="submit" id="QualSav">Save</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default btnCancel" type="button" id="QualCanl">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form:form>
  </div>

</main>
```

**Qualification Model**

package com.hcl.ne.model;

```
public class Qualification {

    private String company;
    private String companyClass;
    private String rule;
/*  private String lastModifiedOn;
    private String lastModifiedBy;*/
    private String status;
    private String[] attributeList;
    private String attributeValue;



    public String getAttributeValue() {
        return attributeValue;
    }
    public void setAttributeValue(String attributeValue) {
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }
    public String[] getAttributeList() {
        return attributeList;
    }
    public void setAttributeList(String[] attributeList) {
        this.attributeList = attributeList;
    }
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    public String getCompanyClass() {
        return companyClass;
    }
    public void setCompanyClass(String companyClass) {
        this.companyClass = companyClass;
    }
    public String getRule() {
        return rule;
    }
    public void setRule(String rule) {
        this.rule = rule;
    }
/*  public String getLastModifiedOn() {
        return lastModifiedOn;
    }
    public void setLastModifiedOn(String lastModifiedOn) {
        this.lastModifiedOn = lastModifiedOn;
    }
    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }
    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }*/
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }




}
```

**Plugin.js**

```
/* Qualification Rule page */
$('#QualRule').on('click', function() {
    $("#QualSerch").hide();
    $("#QualRules").show();
});

    $('#QualAdd').on('click', function() {
    $("#QualEdit").show();
    $("#QualRules").hide();
   /* $("#QualAtt").show();*/


}); 


/*$('#QualSav, #QualCanl').on('click', function() {
    $("#QualEdit").hide();
    $("#QualRules").hide();
    $("#QualSerch").show();
}); 
*/
function switchOption() {
    var  selectedValue= $("#companyClass").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getClass",
        data:'classId='+selectedValue,
        success: function(data){

            var tablebody = $('<tbody>');
            var tablerow = "";
            $(data.resultMenuForLocation).each(function(index){
                tablerow = $('<tr>')
                    .append($('<td>').append($('<input>').attr({type :'checkbox'}).attr('class','checkBoxSize').attr({value : ''+$(this)[0].id}).attr('id','attributeList').attr('name','attributeList')))
                    .append($('<td>').append($(this)[0].dropdownValue+''))
                    .append($('<td>').append($('<input>').attr({type :'text'}).attr('class','form-control').attr('id','attributeValue').attr('name','attributeValue')))
                $(tablebody).append(tablerow);
            });
            $('<table>')
            .attr('id','master_table')
            .attr('class','myAttr f-size-16')
            .html('<thead><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Attribute</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>')
            .append(tablebody)
            .appendTo('div#QualAtt1');

        }

});
    }
```

Comment: Can some one help me on this.

Comment: can you please paste your exact exception log?

Comment: There is no exception log because it is not even hitting controller method after clicking on save it just showing this mentioned message on browser. Console is empty.

Comment: look at network tab in your browser (if chrome then pressing f12) and see what response and code are  return from server and what are request header

Comment: i have seen in network tab(Chrome) i am not able to see anything, nothing is coming. Response code is 400.

Comment: Any possible answer..?

Comment: first just make one simple method in your controller with GET type and try to hit from browser to see if spring mapping is proper or not

Comment: I have tried as per your comment, but I am  getting same error. As per my observation RequestMapping is right.

Comment: have you include jacson dependency in your lib

Comment: i have not, but in the same controller other methods are working fine, as this is simple request mapping

Comment: ok can you give me other methods code, which also have object as parameter and working fine ?

Comment: one more thing i would like to test is just change return type of your method to string and return your pagename instead of model(just to test)